# Password authentication failed, password url encoded

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql, encoding, passwords

My database.yml file is like this:

```
  base: &base   
   adapter: postgres  
   encoding: UTF-8  
   host: hostHidden   
   username: postgres   
   password: passw%#rd   
   schema_search_path: public   
   port: hiddenPort         
   production: &production   
   database: myDb   
  <<: *base
```

I am using DataMapper for my service. Running on postgres 9.5.9. I can also use psql and do all transactions on my db with the same user/pass combination (can connect to db manually).

When my service tries to connect to my db, I get error like this:

```
 DataObjects::SQLError: Can't connect: postgresql://postgres:passw%25%23rd@hostHidden:hiddenPort/myDb?database=myDb&adapter=postgres&encoding=UTF-8&host=hiddenHost&username=postgres&password=passw%2525%2523rd&schema_search_path=public&port=hiddenPort
    FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" (code: , sql state: , query: , uri: )
```

Special characters are encoded, and hence, the authentication is failing.

Update: 
Did some investigation and found out that passwords are url encoded and work perfectly.
Tried to connect to DB manually using:

```
psql 'postgresql://postgres:passw%25%23rd@hostHidden:hiddenPort/myDb'
```

and worked perfectly. But cant figure out why service is not able to connect correctly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what gems are you using? dm-postgres-adapter? Can you connect to the db manually? See this: http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html

Comment: Yes, I am using dm-postgres-adapter. and I am able to connect to db manually.

Comment: I even tried doing: psql 'postgresql://postgres:passw%25%23rd@hostHidden:hiddenPort/m‌​yDb' and I was able to connect to my db (manually)